# Is it possible to index all attributes without knowing exact structure beforehand in arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection with simple documents like this

```
{
key1:value,
key2:value2,
....
}
```

I would like to index **all** keys separately .

But the current arangodb UI only provide  a list of attributes seperated by comma, eg. `[key1,key2]` as input. So I have to define those attributes beforehand

Is there something like * to tell arango to index all attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard indexes do not support wildcards to index all attributes (and multiple paths in an index definition will create a combined index, not a union of all keys). But you can create an **ArangoSearch View** and let it index all attributes:

```
{
  "type": "arangosearch",
  "links": {
    "coll": {
      "analyzers": [
        "identity"
      ],
      "includeAllFields": true
    }
  }
}
```

Then add some documents into the collection `coll`:

- `{"foo": 1}`
- `{"bar": 2}`
- `{"baz": {"nested": 3} }`

And finally query the View (here called `someView`), using the default `identity` Analyzer:

```
FOR doc IN someView
  SEARCH doc.baz.nested == 3
  RETURN doc
```

As you can see, all attributes including nested ones are indexed by the using the `includeAllFields` option at the top-level.

More info: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/arangosearch.html